# Tipsi-Stripe - How to Change Theme

Tags: android, themes, stripe-payments, native-base

I am using Tipsi-Stripe and NativeBase in my react-native, app, but I have not changed any theme variables (to my knowledge), but the components displayed from tipsi stripe seem be in some sort of "dark/night" theme.

Does anybody know where I should be looking to update these theme variables? I have looked at node_modules/native-base/src/theme/variables/ files, but they all appear to be nativebase defaults.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NativeBase does not provide light or dark themes. It comes with `commonColor`, `platform`, `material` themes.

Though you can create light or dark themes on your own

Comment: How do I know which theme to look and how do I know if Native Base styling or tipsi-stripe is styling these components?